# Partial derivatives on connected subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U \subset \mathbb R^{n}$ be open and connected. Let $\space f:U \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable such that $\partial_{1}\space f(x)=0$ for all $x\in U.$ I need to prove or disprove that the value of $f(x)$, for $x=(x_{1},...x_{n})$ does not depend on $x_{1}$.

I tried finding a counter-example $U \subset \mathbb R$ to disprove the claim, but I had no luck, since any open and connected subset of $\mathbb R$ where we can have continuous functions would be an open interval, in which the claim holds (please correct me if my reasoning is wrong).

Could anyone give me some advice on how to find a possible counter-example? Or maybe, if the claim is true, some advice on how to prove it? What I thought about was to use the fact that if $U$ is open and connected in $\mathbb R^{n}$, then it is path connected, but I’m not sure how this would help me prove the claim. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I‘m thinking about non-convex though connected spaces, where going along the 1st coordinate axis does not imply we stay in the connected set

Comment: By going along the 1st coordinate do you mean fixing all other parameters of $f$ other than $x_{1}$? I’m not sure what you mean by stay in the connected set. Could you explain that?

Comment: Picture an open set shaped like a fattened U  (as subset in the euclidian plane) such a domain could be suitable for a function with the desired qualities, and yes fixing the other parameters is what I wanted to allude to

Comment: By the way, connectedness does not imply pathconnectedness, it‘s the other way around

Comment: @VanillaThunder I believe connectedness implies path-connectedness in $\mathbb R^{n}$

Comment: Why should that hold?

Comment: It holds in this context since we are assuming the subset to be open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the set is convex, then one could use the mean value theorem to show that $f$ does not depend on $x_1$. So a counter-example must be on a non-convex set (as was pointed out).

I have a counter-example on the set $U = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{ (0,y): |y|\leq1\}$. The idea is to "paste" two functions which don't depend on $x$ and are zero for $|y|> 1$. Then our new function is smooth other than on the line segment $\{ (0,y): |y|\leq1\}$, which we remove. I provide the counter-example below:

> Define $f:U\to \mathbb R$ by $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} -e^{{-y^2}/(1-y^2)}, & |y|<1, x<0 \\ e^{{-y^2}/(1-y^2)} & |y|<1, x>0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$$

Comment: Trivial remark: for $U$ to be open, you might want to take $|y| \le 1$ instead of $|y| < 1$. Other remark: $\pm (1-y^2)^2$ instead of your exponential would make it more obvious I think. Not adding anything though, fine solution !

Comment: @charMD Yes, I think you are right. I'll change that. Thanks.

Comment: That’s a really nice counter-example. Thanks for the explanation as well!

Comment: @Firage Glad I could help.